# issue with link_to syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Perhaps I am missing something here, but I am having a hard time making this work and any input would be greatly appreciated.I am new to rails and I am trying to make the user experience more friendly.

I want the user to be able to click on a unlocked image and to have it lock itself and vice versa.
I have only attempted my code in the first link_to, I didn't try with the second image because I am already being faced with errors.

Currently my jobs/indes.html.erb file looks like this

```
<td><% if job.locked %>
            <%= link_to(job.locked?(image_tag('lock.png', size: "18x18", alt: "unlocked"),job, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } )) %><%#= link_to 'Edit', edit_job_path(job) %>
        <% else %>
            <%= link_to(image_tag('unlock.png', size: "18x18", alt: "Locked"))%>
        <% end %>.
```

My error is as follows: wrong number of arguments (4 for 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= link_to(image_tag("lock.jpg", :width => 18, :height => 18, alt: "unlocked"), edit_job_path(job) ) %>
```

would be the appropriate `link_to` usage (composed of all data you provided). You are getting such error because (obviously) you pass to many params.

In order to achieve the thing (from what I understand) you want, the path's for `lock` and `unlock` needed.
In the end you would want something like this:

```
<% if job.locked? %>
  <%= link_to(image_tag("lock.jpg", :width => 18, :height => 18, alt: "unlocked"), unlock_job_path(job) ) %>
<% else %>
 <%= link_to(image_tag("lock.jpg", :width => 18, :height => 18, alt: "locked"), lock_job_path(job) ) %>
<% end %>
```